# Getting user info with JWT auth

Tags: javascript, angular, jwt, token

I'm in doubt, how should I get current user info, should I pass it with token while logging in or get it by decoding token and querying by token payload ?

In second case I should make a request every time I need current user info, I guess it's better to have less requests because of performance..

Comment: Depends on the informations you want ... Username ? Token. List of comments ? http call.

Comment: I need it just for displaying online user info like name, username, there is no password or security stuff..

Comment: @merko without posting what you have done, cannot able to help...

Comment: Then sure, store it in your token. As a rule of thumb, store in your tokens values that won't change much overtime, such as username, date of birth, first and last name, address ... (And if you need them of course)

Comment: Save the user ID in the token and get the user object from your DB every time you need it (on the server of course). This should not actually impact performance that much, if you use a no-sql dB

Comment: Thank you so much..